# PyCharm "no module named sys"

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycharm

Using PyCharm community edition and Python 2.7,

```
import traceback
import sys
```

No problem on the first line, which implies that I have pointed PyCharm correctly at the interpreter. However, I get "no module named sys" at the second line (which is strange, as sys is a builtin - if you can find the interpreter, you have found sys).

Any ideas?

---

[Update] to the commentators so far, thanks.

The IDE does not offer `sys` for auto-complete after `import sy`.

When I start the interpreter which the IDE uses form the command line, then `import sys` works.

Comment: Does it autocomplete if you type `import sy`?

Comment: i think you manually have to set the root for sys in pycharm

Comment: If you open a python session in the terminal, can you import it?

Comment: Had this issue once, could not resolve it. But it was and IDE only issue. Running, debugging, using terminal, python console, every thing worked fine.

Comment: is this solved? If not - I'm wondering if you're using a remote interpreter. Not sure if that'd help anybody in debugging your situation, but just in case.

Comment: That depends on Python flavour. See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-23590

Comment: @BrynnMcCullagh 's answer should be the accepted one

Comment: It is - and has been for 3 years :-)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I have had this issue with PyCharm before.  I find that reloading the interpreter fixes the issue.

File -> Settings -> Project -> Project Interpreter

Remove the interpreter and add it again.

Comment: Or even just 'apply' a different one, and back.

Comment: At the first the issue is disappeared, but when I try to enter another call to `sys.` PyCharm marks all line with "sys" as error.

Comment: @Kixoms are you using `conda` by any chance? I had an issue where if I pointed to wrong python binary (not within the `envs` folder), it would give me the above error.

Comment: Good fix, also works for the CLion python environment.

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem as well and was completely stymied until I tried the following:

```
File -> 
Default Settings -> 
Project Interpreter
  dropdown (click the arrow) ->
Show All ->
  select your interpreter ->
Show Paths
  (bottom icon on right) ->
Add Path ->
  Enter path to libraries
  (in my case this was c:\Python35\Lib).
```

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you've chosen the right Interpreter path and check some other run settings. Go to **Run > Edit Configurations...** and check, if some configurations seem to be wrong.

**EDIT:** Under Linux, you have often Python 2 and 3 installed, be sure to pick the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and I resolved it by updating the default project settings under File -> Default Settings -> Project Interpreter and then in the drop down list for Project Interpreter, selecting the same interpreter as the Run Configuration was using (in my case python 3.6)

Answer (score -1):

PyCharm has virtual Enviroment and System Interpreter. Select system interpreter

[image]

Answer (score -1):

We actually no need of having "import sys" in pycharm. You can find this in 'os' module.

For example,

```
import os

Sys = os.sys

print("say , Good Bye")


Sys.exit(0)

print("Sorry, i am not exited")
```

I hope it will work.

Comment: This does work since [`os.sys`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/os.py#L26) is the `os` module's import of `sys`. But, it's more of a "private" implementation of `os`, and could change in between versions. It's still much safer to just import `sys` directly.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you're updating your PYTHONPATH variable in your .bashrc file? 
It started working on, after comment PATH PATH in bash_profile.

Answer (score -2):

File -> Settings -> Project: (your_project_name) -> Project Interpreter -> press the + symbol -> search for 'system' and install package.

This solved the problem for me.